# Unable to access Server via UNC path

Tags: windows

Can someone help me out. I am enterned new to this IT field and trying to do practice lab at home.

I have a windows 2012 server and windows 7 client pc. Trying to access server from client pc. I get the dialog box asking to enter username and password for my domain. I enter the correct credentials and it doesn't work. At the bottom of the same dialog box there is a message saying "Access denied"

I am able to ping from client to the server and vice versa but unable to access the server using the client pc.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NL17P.jpg)

Please help!

Comment: What does “Trying to access the server from client PC” mean? You’re trying to RDP, Remote Management, access a file, etc???? What specifically are you doing on the client PC that isn’t working?

Comment: Hey, thanks for your quick reply. I have created a folder on the server and want to try and access it through the client pc. I entered \\192.168.1.2 which is my server ip address. I get dialog box to enter username and password for my domain but at the bottom of the same dialog box, it says access denied.

Comment: sorry if I am not able to convey the message correctly. This is like a starting phase for me.

Comment: i type the ip address by pressing windows key + R. That is called the UNC path I guess

Comment: On the server, press windows+r and type lusrmgr.msc . Since it is a lab, make sure the domain user you are using to connect is in the administrator group under "groups". Now, when you connect with the win7pc, type \\1.2.3.4\c$ , where the numbers are the ip of the server. This will give you access to the entire c drive of the server.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your settings, entering the IP address might not be enough.  You need to include the share name, as well.  For example:

```
\\192.168.1.2\MyFolder
```

And it should go without saying, the remote folder needs to be shared to the user accessing it with the proper share *and* file/folder permissions.